# Buffered iterator with the io.* classes

Tags: python, buffer

When writing to a file in a setting like the following, where `production.iterlines()` generates many lines of text:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    for line in production.iterlines():
        f.write(line)
```

then – if I understand correctly – the following happens:
The TextIOWrapper object `f` accepts line by line, encodes it, and, whenever a certain limit is reached (eg. 4096 bytes in the buffer), writes a chunk of bytes to disk. So the actual disk-writing operations are not at the same pace as the lines yielded, but typically less frequent (unless the lines are very long).

Now I would like to have an *iterator* over these chunks, eg. for sending them over a network. It could be used like this:

```
for chunk in BufferedIterator(production.iterlines()):
    # do something with the chunk
```

So this hypothetical BufferedIterator object assembles strings from its argument into chunks of reasonable size and yields them to its caller as encoded bytes.

I feel like this should be possible with a clever combination of the classes in the `io` module – I just can't get my head around how to use them. Something like StringIO, but with some kind of queue behaviour, with interleaved write and read calls.

But maybe I'm wrong and they aren't designed for this kind of task. (After all, it's not that hard to piece together an iterator that encodes and concatenates strings until a fixed chunk size is reached.) Answers are encouraged to give me a better understanding of the *usage* of the `io` classes. I am very fond of the official documentation usually, but the one on the `io` module just leaves me behind hopelessly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use *any* `io` classes here. You are not really performing I/O, only buffering (which is not unique to I/O). Trying to re-use the `BufferIOBase` interface is sub-optimal here, since your input is an iterable, and so is your output; neither is a file-like object and no `.read()` is available for a `BufferedReader()` to fill the buffer from.

You can implement the class yourself; I used the [`collections.deque()` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to keep this as efficient as possible:

```
from collections import deque

class BufferedIterator:
    """Turns an iterable of str lines into chunks of a fixed size"""
    def __init__(self, it, buffer=2**12):
        self._it = iter(it)
        self._buffersize = buffer
        self._lengths, self._lines = deque(), deque()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._it is None:
            raise StopIteration

        # collect enough lines to fill the buffer
        bsize = self._buffersize
        while sum(self._lengths) < bsize:
            line = next(self._it, None)
            if line is None:
                # out of data, build the chunk from the remainder
                # clear the iterable to flag that we are done
                self._it = None
                if not self._lines:
                    # edgecase, never had any lines to begin with
                    raise StopIteration
                break
            self._lines.append(line)
            self._lengths.append(len(line))

        # build a chunk from the buffered lines
        chunklength = 0
        chunk = []
        while self._lines and chunklength < bsize:
            length, linechunk = self._lengths.popleft(), self._lines.popleft()
            needed = bsize - chunklength
            if length > needed:
                # only need a substring
                self._lengths.appendleft(length - needed)
                self._lines.appendleft(linechunk[needed:])
                length, linechunk = needed, linechunk[:needed]
            chunklength += length
            chunk.append(linechunk)
        return ''.join(chunk)

    next = __next__  # Python 2
```

By using two `deque` objects, one for the lengths, and one for the lines themselves, we avoid having to call `len()` too often. Getting the length of a string is cheap enough, but pushing and popping the current stack frame to retrieve it each time is costly enough to want to avoid this.

Demo:

```
>>> for chunk in BufferedIterator(['The quick brown fox ', 'jumps over ', 'the lazy dog'], 16):
...     print(repr(chunk))
...
'The quick brown '
'fox jumps over t'
'he lazy dog'
>>> import random, string
>>> def random_lines(number=100, minlength=60, maxlength=80):
...     for _ in range(number):
...         yield ''.join([random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(random.randrange(minlength, maxlength))])
...
>>> for chunk in BufferedIterator(random_lines(200)):
...     print(len(chunk))
...
4096
4096
4096
1710
>>> for chunk in BufferedIterator(random_lines(2000, 2, 20)):
...     print(len(chunk))
...
4096
4096
4096
4096
4096
428
>>> for chunk in BufferedIterator(random_lines(3, 5000, 6000)):
...     print(len(chunk))
...
4096
4096
4096
3960
```

Comment: Thanks, Martijn. I'm a bit disappointed that the whole buffering logic needs to be rebuilt... I mean, there's StringIO, which doesn't do any IO either, it just simulates it, offering the consumer-side interface. So I figured that there might be a simulator for the other side, too.

Comment: `StringIO` requires the whole string to be available as one big chunk, which an iterable doesn't provide. Buffering is used in many different contexts; you just don't have an I/O context here.

Comment: Besides, you don't need to build anything, I just did it for you ;-)

Comment: Sure, thanks :). But is calling `len()` often really an issue? I'd rather try to avoid the unconditioned slice on `line` in the second while loop, as it's will be the whole line in most cases.

Comment: Oh, you already changed that last thing :-). I'll come back when you're happy with the code!

Comment: @lenz: all done; I was indeed trying to replace the unconditional slice with something a little smarter.

Comment: Ok, one more thought (maybe I should post a new question for this): How would the picture change if I were to use `csv.writer` "between" the two iterators? Ie. the underlying iterator yields tuples, these are interpolated to strings with `csv`, and then the chunk buffering takes place. Use a BufferedWriter as an attribute to BufferedIterator?

Comment: @lenz: `csv.writer` expects to *write* to a file object. At that point you do need something implementing a file-like object, so `io.BufferedWriter` would  start to make sense. But then you need to give that one another object to write to in turn. In other words, once you add `csv.writer` you *are* building an I/O chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129231/discussion-between-lenz-and-martijn-pieters).